# Coldfusion SOAP API, name of parameters on wsdl changes to generic one

Tags: soap, coldfusion, adobe

I have a legacy SOAP API built in Coldfusion. This API is well established and works most times, until it doesn't but just for some third parties integrating with it.
The issue I am facing is quite odd, I have checked the logs but not able to pinpoint why it occurs or when.

This is what the API Method in question looks like when I access the wsdl directly from browser:

[image]

As you can see the parameters names are defined and listed as expected; however quite regularly, after the API gets used for sometime (once again, I am not able to find out when it occurs unfortunately nor why it does), the parameter names change to the following:

[image]

At this stage, some of the third party software's integrating with this API get the following error message back from Coldfusion:

> coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCInvocationException: [coldfusion.runtime.MissingArgumentException : The TOKEN parameter to the SubmitJobApplication function is required but was not passed in.]

I originally believed that the issue could be caused by the parameters not being passed in the exact same order as what Coldfusion expects them to be, however the code snippets I have been provided by the developers from one of these third party softwares show the parameters being passed in the correct order.

The simplest solution I have found to fix the issue (until it occurs again) is to save the CFC template again by adding/removing an empty space anywhere within the template; it is kind of refreshing the wsdl.

Another thing to note is that we are using Coldfusion 2023 and we have recently upgraded from 2018 (and before then 2016) however we were already experiencing it, so it doesn't seem to relate to this upgrade process.

Has anyone experienced the same issue with Coldfusion with the name of the parameters changing?

Comment: Have you checked other files in the directory to make sure there is no copies with different parameters. The strange thing about the difference is that the second param also has a different type, which might suggest it's reading a different file. Is there any load balancing or file replication in play?

Comment: @haxtbh the server on which this API resides is not load balanced and there is no file replication happening. In that folder, this is the only template available; also, if i add and then remove a space and save the changes, the file starts working again and shows the correct parameter names.

Comment: @haxtbh, I have just noticed that I have provided the screenshots while I was debugging some changes and that's the reason for the difference between the type of the second parameter string vs boolean. Just replicated the issue and it is showing correctly as string now, but the issue still persists

Comment: do you think you could pinpoint a time that it worked and perhaps stopped working after a particular hotfix, in any of the previous versions of CF you used. Maybe a bug has been introduced somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am not able to pinpoint a time to be honest but you are right, it could very well be something that was introduced as part of a particular update. I might have to reach out direclty to Adobe support and ask them to look into it as it is quite an odd one.

Comment: I have found the reason causing the parameters names to change and it is the fact that one of the third party systems consuming the API, sends requests with the parameters not in the same order as specficied in the function. As soon as that occurs, Coldfusion changes the names of the parameters to in0, in1, in2 etc
Now i need to find a way to fix that (if any)